# Assigning colours to groups of rows/columns in Python Plotly heatmaps

Tags: plotly, seaborn, heatmap, plotly-python, imshow

Is there a way to use `plotly` in Python to generate a heatmap (e.g., through `imshow`) and assign different colours to different groups of rows/columns? The goal is to generate a plot similar to the `clustermap` that can be generated with `seaborn` without dendrograms but with external colours of the rows/columns to indicate distinct groups, as shown in the example attached here below and obtained from [seaborn's documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.clustermap.html) where rows are assigned with different colours for indicating `species`:

```py
lut = dict(zip(species.unique(), "rbg"))
row_colors = species.map(lut)
g = sns.clustermap(iris, row_colors=row_colors)
```

In particular, is there a solution to this using `plotly.express` and starting from (or using directly) data within a `pandas`'s `DataFrame`?

[image: final goal obtained with seaborn]

Comment: Hi and welcome on SO. It will be great if you can have a look at [how-to-ask](/help/how-to-ask) and then try to produce a [mcve](/help/mcve).

Comment: I have added the code from `seaborn` reported link to reproduce the figure that was already included in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding colours to distinguish groups of rows/columns on a Heatmap can be achieved using subplots, where one row/column hetamaps are used to distinguish groups. An example is shown here below:

```
fig = make_subplots(rows=2, cols=2, column_widths=[0.9, 0.1], row_heights=[0.9, 0.1], vertical_spacing=0.02)
table = pd.pivot_table(df, index='A', columns='B', values='C', aggfunc='first')
fig.append_trace(go.Heatmap(z=table, colorscale = 'bugn', colorbar={'x' : 1.1, 'y' : 0.5}), row=1, col=1)
fig.append_trace(go.Heatmap(z=df1, colorscale='spectral', showscale=False), row=1, col=2)
fig.append_trace(go.Heatmap(z=df2, colorscale='plasma', showscale=False), row=2, col=1)
fig.update_layout(xaxis2_showticklabels=False, yaxis2_showticklabels=False,
                  xaxis3_showticklabels=False, yaxis3_showticklabels=False,
                  xaxis_side='top')
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: @zacca- Can you please add more info regarding `df`, `df1`, and `df2`?  I'm trying to add grouping labels to my heatmap rows (using Plotly) and find it difficult to understand from your answer how to apply it on the  `iris` dataset. many thanks!

Comment: df = pd.DataFrame([{'A' : 1, 'B' : 1, 'C' : 1}, {'A' : 1, 'B' : 2, 'C' : 2}, {'A' : 2, 'B' : 1, 'C' : 3}, {'A' : 2, 'B' : 2, 'C' : 4}])

df1 = pd.DataFrame([{'A' : -1}, {'A' : -2}])

df2 = pd.DataFrame([{'B' : 1}, {'B' : 2}]).T